# How do I minify all assets EXCEPT jQuery in Yii?

Tags: php, jquery, yii, yii2

Yii lets you minify and compress JS. I want to compress all the app's JS and use Google's hosted jQuery. How do I do this?

Yii lets you specify the source for jQuery http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#customizing-asset-bundles

But I'm already using the `bundles` key for the [compressed assets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#an-example):

```
'bundles' => require(__DIR__ . '/' . (YII_ENV_PROD ? 'assets-prod.php' : 'assets-dev.php')),
```

`assets-prod.php` is automatically generated. I tried customizing the asset bundle during the compression with this

`assets.php`

```
// Asset manager configuration:
'assetManager' => [
    'basePath' => '@webroot/assets',
    'baseUrl' => '@web/assets',
    'bundles' => [
      'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
        'sourcePath' => null,   // do not publish the bundle
        'js' => [
          '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js',
        ],
      ],
    ],
],
```

But when I ran `yii asset assets.php config/assets-prod.php` it didn't generate any jQuery files at all. That is almost what I wanted, but when I loaded the page, jQuery was missing entirely. There was no reference to jQuery. It created this in `assets-prod.php`, which seems wrong

```
'yii\\web\\JqueryAsset' => [
    'sourcePath' => null,
    'js' => [],
    'css' => [],
    'depends' => [],
],
```

Ok so I then tried Asset Mapping http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#asset-mapping. I put this into `web.php`

```
      'assetMap' => [
        'jquery.js' => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js',
      ],
```

However, it still would not load jQuery. I reverted `assets.php` and ran `yii asset assets.php config/assets-prod.php` again, but then it went back to putting jQuery into the one large minified JS file.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use "baseUrl" property, like this:

```
class GoogleAsset extends AssetBundle{

    public $baseUrl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api';

    public $js = [
        'js?sensor=false&language=ru-ru&region=ru-ru'
    ];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this configuration

```
'yii\\web\\JqueryAsset' => [
    'baseUrl' => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/',
    'js' => ['jquery.min.js'],
    'css' => [],
    'depends' => [],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

you no need basURL

```
<?php

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class GoogleApiAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $js = ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'];
}
```